# Show list when clicking md-contact-chips

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm using `md-contact-chips` from [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/1.0.4/api/directive/mdContactChips%20%22%22). It's working great, but I would like to display the full list when clicking on the input and no text is entered.

I tried returning the entire list when the query string is an space character with the same function used in `md-contacts` but this function is not triggered with space characters. How can I achieve this?

Comment: There's a comment [here](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2423) that suggests using `md-min-length="0"`, but there's no example and I haven't got it working yet.

Comment: @Nick yes, I tried that but it didn't work. I ended up using Boostrap UI dropdown but I'm still interested in a solution.